# How to wrap the text to next line in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

In crystal report  string which is coming from database contains 100 characters,I need to display the characters in 3 or 4 lines basing on length of object in crystal report.
For that i checked can grow option and maximum number of lines as 3 or 4 lines,But when I run it is showing only some characters and others are invisible.Here the whole text should display which is coming from database.

Comment: I tried with 0 but still there is no change

Comment: If you have no white-space or other delimiters in your data, then Crystal won't wrap lines. Probably you should create formula, which inserts some spaces into string values.

Comment: There is no white space in my data.First time when I run it I didn't check the can grow property.For the second time it is checked,but it is not taking the changes after running the application.I wrote crystalreportviewer.Refresh(); also

Comment: On;y option is set can grow to 0

Comment: Now I mentioned Can Grow is 0 but no correct output

Comment: I wrote - create formula, which inserts some spaces into your data.

Comment: I tried the formula that is {field} + {Chrw(300)}

Answer (score 1):

Try put `0` to Can grow Max Lines option. `0` is Infinite.

Comment: I tried it with 0 and without 0 that is 3 or 4.But still it is same